# "Create Database" error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database. But i get an error while i'm doing.

**This is the code :**

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx")
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("alpMuhendislik",$link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE alpMuhendislik';
    if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
        echo "Database alpMuhendislik created successfully\n";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

**And this is the error :**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ..../load_data.php on line 3

I just couldn't see any problem about syntax. I checked marks and semicolons.

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a `;` here: `$link = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");` Also, that's a PHP parse error, nothing to do with MySQL or create statements or whatnot.

Comment: What does that question have to do with error 1064?

Comment: You checked your semicolons? Really?

Comment: @lanzz Sorry about that. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing `;`:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx")
                                             ^^^
```

"Unexpected *something* on line x" typically means there's a problem on line x-1.

Comment: Of course! I feel like a dumb.

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
```